# How to identify and wire leads on a one phase 6 lead, capacitor start, capacitor run electric motor

Tags: capacitor, single-phase, winding, volts

The leads are labeled U1, U2, U5, U6, Z1, and Z2.  My research has found wiring diagrams on 4 lead motors where U1 & U2 are main winding and Z1 & Z2 are auxilary winding. Start capacitor wired to auxilary winding. Run to both.
Not sure what U5 and U6 are. Does this motor have three windings ? Not sure how to wire in the capacitors either . Anyone familar with this arrangement . The motor is of Swiss (German) origin

Comment: Where's the photo, Jim? Where's the photo!

Comment: Connecting the motor will be very difficult without a diagram that should be on the rating plate on the outer surface of the motor or on the inside of the wiring box cover.

Comment: The motor may be a dual-voltage motor. There may be two main windings that can be connected in series or parallel with each other. The auxiliary winding may have a center connection for the lower voltage. There is also the possibility that the motor is rated for one voltage but two speeds.